# Given a function $f(x)$ that verifies the following conditions

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, even-and-odd-functions

I have a function that verifies the following conditions:

$f(x)$ is even

$f(5)=6$

$f(x)$ belongs to $[0,5)$ for $x \in [-2,-1]$

It increases in $(- \infty ,-6)$

$\lim_{x\to 6+ } = + \infty$

The activity says:

1) Are the following statements true?:

I) $0 \le f(1,5) \le 6 $

II) The limit $f(x)$ when $x$ approaches 5 from the right is 6

2) What can you say about the evenness or oddness of $f(3x), f(x+3), 3f(x) and f(x)+3$ ?

I need some hints to do it.

Comment: Instead of trying to find an explicit function it's instructive to first try to make a sketch of a function satisfying all the requirements (use that it's even to translate $f(5)$ to $f(-5)$ and only draw it for $x<0$ and then mirror the result to get the full function).

Comment: If this is really the whole question then your instructor should be willing to accept a sketch of the graph of such a function. You are not asked for a formula. In any case I suggest you begin by sketching such a graph. (Last point: the limit statement at the end of your question is incomplete. What should that limit be?)

Comment: @EthanBolker I've edited the question. I hadn't understood the activity

Comment: @Winther I've edited the question. I hadn't understood the activity

Comment: Same advice: try to draw a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Statement II is false, as $f(5)=6$ but this gives us no information about the limits (it would if we knew $f$ is continuous, but we are making no such assumption) I don't really understand what I is really asking. For the rest:

$f(3x) = f(-3x) $ because $f$ is even. So, if $g(x)=f(3x)$, $g$ is an even function
$f(x+3) =f(-x-3)$ which does not necessarelly equal $f(-x+3)$, so you will easily find a counterexample on that one.
The remaining are very easy reasoning in a similar way

Comment: Thank you! As for 1)I) I made a mistake typing it, I've just edited it